# css file not working from localhost for some web pages

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying a javascript to change the background of any loaded web page from firefox. I have apache web server installed. I run the below code on any site (for example stackoverflow.com) after the site is loaded from the console of the firebug.

Test 1: css file from localhost

```
var s = document.createElement('link');
s.setAttribute('href', 'http://localhost/new1.css');
s.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
alert('Stylesheet injected!');
```

the above code works for stackoverflow.com wikipidea.com. the new1.css file loads from local server successfully. BUt this code does not work for google.com and yahoo.com and many other.

the content of the `http://localhost/new1.css`

```
body { background-color: #0000ee !important; }
```

I run the code in the firebug console and the following appears in the head of the html

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/new1.css">
```

Test2: css file from dropbox

```
var s = document.createElement('link');
s.setAttribute('href', 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cdio6v4wiqj7g1i/new1.css?dl=1&token_hash=AAFsujreqLbTBoBcn5oF4CE0x2YKzuZG4RbYS27W0b0TUA');
s.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
s.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
alert('Stylesheet injected!');
```

Result: works on any site:

the content of the `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cdio6v4wiqj7g1i/new1.css?dl=1&token_hash=AAFsujreqLbTBoBcn5oF4CE0x2YKzuZG4RbYS27W0b0TUA`

```
body { background-color: #0000ee !important; }
```

I run the code in the firebug console and the following appears in the head of the html

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cdio6v4wiqj7g1i/new1.css?dl=1&token_hash=AAFsujreqLbTBoBcn5oF4CE0x2YKzuZG4RbYS27W0b0TUA">
```

Can anyone figure out why css file supplied via localhost doesnot work whereas same css file supplied from dropbox works for google.com

Comment: might be a cache issue, try to load your page in a Google Chrome "incognito window"

Comment: Sorry i gone through that. but here i am trying directly from document root. You see localhost/new1.css without any .public_html etc

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I didn't look close enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load resources from HTTP in HTTPS websites.

If you look at the console, you'll see a warning explaining that.

Comment: It shows in firebug. Blocked loading mixed active content "http://localhost/new1.css"

Comment: is there any way out then, I want to use as greasmonkey script